# NHibernate mapping - two fields refereing to same table

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a table ExchangeRate which has the following 4 fields and relationship

- Id - Unique Id,
- CurrencyFrom - Foreign key to Currency table,
- CurrencyTo - Foreignkey to Currency table.
- ExchangeRate - double

I created a mapping file like below

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="NHibernateService" assembly="NHibernateService">
  <class name="Entity" table="ExchangeRate" entity-name="ExchangeRate">
    <id name="id" column="id">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <dynamic-component name="Attributes">
      <property name="ExchangeRate" column="ExchangeRate" type="double" />
      <many-to-one name="Currency" class="Entity" entity-name="Currency" column="CurrencyFrom" lazy="false" />
      <many-to-one name="Currency" class="Entity" entity-name="Currency" column="CurrencyTo" lazy="false" />
    </dynamic-component>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

It throws out an error as it has 2 fields reffering to the same table.
What changes are required in the mapping file for this scenario? 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in a **`name`** attribute of the `many-to-one` element. Simply there can NOT be two same names. It is the same as in C#, this won't compile:

```
public class Entity
{
    public virtual int      id           { get; set; }
    public virtual Currency Currency     { get; set; }
    public virtual Currency Currency     { get; set; } // the same name twice
    public virtual double   ExchangeRate { get; set; }
}
```

The above mapping is 1:1 to provided xml mapping in the question. The Name of two properties is the same **Currency**... we have to change it like this *(in C#)*:

```
public class Entity
{
    public virtual int      id           { get; set; }
    public virtual Currency CurrencyFrom { get; set; }
    public virtual Currency CurrencyTo   { get; set; } // different names
    public virtual double   ExchangeRate { get; set; }
}
```

And the same *(as discussed above on C# entity level)*, must be applied to mapping. Also, the class attribute must represent its property type *(i.e. Currency)*.

```
<many-to-one name="CurrencyFrom" class="Currency" column="CurrencyFrom" lazy="false" />
<many-to-one name="CurrencyTo"   class="Currency" column="CurrencyTo"   lazy="false" />
```

NOTE: that all expects, that similar way is mapped Table *[Currency]* into `Currency` class

Comment: Thank you very much. Also I have another issue. How do i map if need to have a self join. For example Company and ParentCompany in the same table where Parent company can be null

Comment: It is almost the same.. nothing special. Check this http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#example-parentchild-bidir The Parent must have not-null="true" ... really very standard mapping ;) If you will not succeed... raise a question with mapping you managed to have... ;)

Comment: <dynamic-component name="Attributes">
          <property name="Company" column="Company" type="string" length="50" />
          <many-to-one name="ParentCompany" class="Entity" entity-name="Company" column="ParentCompany" lazy="false" />
        </dynamic-component>